# Don't deploy a *.dll on which other *.dll's depend on but which is never called? and how to compile?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, dll, deployment

currently I develop a Qt4 Project in VS2010 with 3rd party libraries (QGis). When I start the release, the prompt tells me, which *.dll's are missing and have to be copied to the Release Folder. So far so good, the Program is running without problems. 
My Questions: Dependency Walker shows me the dependencies of the dll's. Some are dependent but they are never used. How can I tell the compiler to ignore these dependencies and just to consider those dll's which are actually called? The intent is to make the deploy as small as possible.

Kindly,
Olle Onkel

Comment: Maybe you don't need to link against those libraries whose API your program does not use?

Comment: It's been a while since I really looked into Dependency Walker, but IIRC it also used to tell you **why** those DLLs are dependencies.